# Comparing two elements in an different array of structs?

Tags: c, io, set

I have two files, `cars.txt` and `reservation.txt`, both of the files have `resID` in common.

I want the user to enter a date, use that date to see the cars that are **unavailable**, then print them (through `resID`).

car.txt:
(From left to right: `reservationID`, `carID`, `carYOM`, `carMake`, `carModel`, `carFuel`, `catagory`.)

```
R001;V001;2003;Toyota;Camry;Petrol;Budget
R002;V002;2005;Toyota;Prius;Petrol;Economy
R003;V003;1999;Ford;Falcon;Petrol;Midsize
R004;V004;2007;Ford;Territory;Diesel;Fullsize
R005;V005;2010;Ferrari;599;Petrol;Fullsize
R006;V006;1998;Holden;Comadore;Diesel;Midsize
R007;V007;2008;Honda;Civic;Petrol;Budget
R008;V008;2000;Mazda;MX5;Petrol;Economy
```

reservation.txt:
(From left to right: `reservationID`, `customerID`, `reservationStartDate`, `reservationStartTime`, `reservationEndDate`, `reservationEndTime`.)

```
R001;C005;2012/02/12;09:15A.M;2012/03/15;05:00P.M
R002;C002;2012/04/15;10:00A.M;2012/04/22;10:30A.M
R003;C003;2012/01/16;02:11P.M;2012/04/15;12:00P.M
R004;C004;2012/05/05;03:00P.M;2012/05/08;10:40A.M
R005;C005;2012/05/15;10:00A.M;2012/04/23;05:00P.M
R006;C006;2012/04/11;05:30P.M;2012/04/15;10:00A.M
R007;C008;2012/05/15;03:15P.M;2012/05/18;11:00A.M
R008;C007;2012/04/15;11:40P.M;2012/04/23;09:00A.M
```

The code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CAR 100
#define MAX_RES 100

int main(){

    typedef struct{                 //car struct
        char reservationID[20];
        char carID[20];
        char carYOM[20];
        char carMake[20];
        char carModel[50];
        char carFuel[20];
        char catagory[20];
    } car_t;

    typedef struct{                 //res struct
        char reservationID[20];
        char customerID[20];
        char reservationStartDate[20];
        char reservationStartTime[20];
        char reservationEndDate[50];
        char reservationEndTime[20];
    } res_t;

    car_t car[MAX_CAR];             //car array
    res_t reservation[MAX_RES];     //res array
    FILE *carHandle;
    FILE *resHandle;
    char line[100];
    char *item;
    int rescount = 0;
    int carcount =0;
    int k;
    int i;
    int option;
    char choice[20];    

    resHandle = fopen("reservation.txt","r");    

    while (fgets(line, 99, resHandle)){
      //cut up the reservation file line by line and put the bits into the res array.
        item = strtok(line,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].customerID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationStartDate,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationStartTime,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationEndDate,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,"\n");
        strcpy(reservation[rescount].reservationEndTime,item);
        rescount++;
    }

    fclose(resHandle);

    carHandle = fopen("car.txt","r");    

    while (fgets(line, 99, carHandle)){
        //cut up the car file line by line and put the bits into the car array.
        item = strtok(line,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].reservationID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carID,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carYOM,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carMake,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carModel,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,";");
        strcpy(car[carcount].carFuel,item);
        item = strtok(NULL,"\n");
        strcpy(car[carcount].catagory,item);
        carcount++;
    }

    fclose(carHandle);

    printf("Enter todays date (in YYYY/MM/DD format):");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    for (k=0;k<=rescount; k++){
        if (strcmp(choice,reservation[k].reservationStartDate)>=0 && strcmp(choice,reservation[k].reservationStartDate)>=0){
            for (i=0;i<=carcount; i++){
                if (strcmp(car[i].reservationID,reservation[i].reservationID)==0){
                    printf("\nreservationID: %s\nreservationStartTime: %s\ncustomerID: %s\ncarid: %s\nyom: %s\nmake: %s\nmodel: %s\nfueltype: %s\ncategory: %s\n\n", car[k].reservationID, reservation[i].reservationStartTime, reservation[i].customerID, car[k].carID, car[k].carYOM, car[k].carMake, car[k].carModel, car[k].carFuel, car[k].catagory);
                    goto outofloop;
                }
            }
        }else printf("\nall the cars are available\n");
        break;
    }
    outofloop:

    return(0);
}
```

Currently the code only works with input strings '2012/02/12' to '2012/03/15' (i.e the first line of the reservation file)

Any other input string will not get past the first if statement.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: `for (k=0;k<rescount; k++){` Similar for carcount.

Comment: Why not just use `grep` and `cut`?

Comment: Yes, it is homework. However I have worked very hard on it and I am getting stuck on a particular part that I need some guidance on. I have provided sample code, given you the unexpected results, shown the input values it works for, and narrowed down the problem to an IF statement.

Please be more considerate to those who do not have the knowledge to write hundreds of perfect code without breaking a sweat.

To the other people who replied: Thank you.

@wildplasser, I need to use i to cycle through the the second loop? I'm not exactly sure what you mean here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you only test the first reservation.

```
for (k = 0; k < rescount; k++) {
    if () {
    } else {
    }
    break;
}
```

Also note the loop control should have `<` only (like in the code above), not `<=` as in your code.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. Amazing how a single break statement can bring down your entire program.

Thanks again for your help.